# I can't understand why Ahlfors' statement is true (isolation of singular points)

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, elliptic-functions

In Ahlfors' complex analysis text, page 264, he writes:

> When $\Omega$ is the whole plane $F(\zeta)$ has **isolated** singularities at $\zeta = 0$ and $\zeta=\infty $.

Reading the previous sections, I assume that $\Omega \subset \mathbb C$ is a region invariant under the translations $z \mapsto z+ \omega,z \mapsto z- \omega$, where $\omega \in \mathbb C$ is some constant. $F(\zeta)=f(z)$ where $\zeta=\exp(2 \pi i z/ \omega)$, and $f$ is some meromorphic function in $\Omega$. Also we denote that image of $\Omega$ under $\zeta(z)$ by $\Omega'$.

Here is (what appears to me as) a counterexample to Ahlfors' statement:

Construct a function $f(z)$ meromorphic in $\Omega=\mathbb C$ with periods $\omega, i \omega$, with $\omega \in \mathbb R$, whose poles form the lattice $\{m \omega+i n \omega:m,n \in \mathbb Z \}$. The sequence of poles $\{i \omega n\}_1^\infty$ in the $z$-plane corresponds to the sequence of poles $\{e^{-2 \pi n} \}$ in the $\zeta$-plane, which tends to the point $\zeta=0$.

This shows that $\zeta=0$ is **not** an isolated singularity of $F(\zeta)$, (the situation at $\infty$ is identical).

Is my reasoning correct, or is Ahlfors right after all? If I'm wrong, please show me why.

Thanks!

Comment: Curious, but isn't the real problem a little higher when he says `it is evident that $F$ is meromorphic`? At least, I'm not able to convince myself right now.

Comment: @JonathanY. That part is not a problem. The exponential map is a covering map $\mathbb C\to \mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$; a meromorphic function on $\mathbb C$ lifts locally (simply by composition with local inverse of $\exp$), and if it is $\omega$-periodic, then the lift is well-defined on  $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right: $0$ and $\infty$ need not be isolated. As Ahlfors himself says in the last sentence of 1.1, every meromorphic map on  $F:\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$ arises from some $f$, namely from $f(z)=F(\exp(2\pi i z/\omega))$. A meromorphic function on $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$ can easily have poles accumulating to either $0$ or $\infty$, or both.

As a fix, omit "isolated" from the quoted sentence, and  perhaps soften it to "may have singularities" because the statement "has singularities" reads as a definite indication of some singular behavior.